# Purpose of the representation theory of Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I will start with the concrete setting: Given a Lie ring $\mathcal{g}$ and a vector space $V$, which is closed under multiplication, a represenation of the Lie ring $\mathcal g$ is a structure preserving map, namely a additive and multiplicative homomorphism $\phi:\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b) \text{ and } \phi(a\cdot b)=[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ where the $"[]"$ is the Lie bracket. Such a mapping is called as faithful if it is injective.

My understanding of the purpose of such representation is that we can investigate the property of the Lie ring by considering its representation, namely the elements in the vector space V.

> Question: Does such representation need to be surjective? If not, I could have some elements in V, which have no correspondence in the Lie Ring. If I investigate the structure of V, I could have some larger space V than my original Lie Ring. So is it not more appropriate if we consider the image of $\phi$, which is a subspace of V. Or is it irrelevant if we are only interested in algebraic structure and not the set structure?

Comment: No. The reason we don't require this is because the structure of all representations of a Lie algebra together is much nicer this way.

Comment: You seem to assume that the values $\phi(a)$ of your representation are vectors in $V$. I'd have expected them to be linear transformations $V\to V$ (so that I know what $[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ means).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you emphasise this bit more? If I am working with the element from $V$. How can I be sure that I do not use elements, which don‘t lies in the image of the homomorphism.

Comment: First of all, $\phi$ is not a map to $V$, it's a map to $\text{End}(V)$. Are you asking about elements of $\text{End}(V)$ which aren't in the image?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree, I am using here a more general definition. I only require a vector space with multiplication being closed. So is my lie-Bracket well defined.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, exactly. Maybe to be more specific. I am interested in the representation of a Lie Ring by a Non-commutative formal series.(which can be identified as a free algebra) I think this build again a ring and I do not really want to specify it as an action V. That’s why I am giving a very general definition, all I need is to require the addition and multiplication being closed such that the Lie Bracket is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments got a bit off-track because a vector space does not generally have a multiplication operation.  When we talk about a vector space $V$ in the context of Lie algebra representations, most people think of homomorphisms from a Lie algebra into $End(V)$, the Lie algebra of endomorphisms of $V$ (which does have a multiplication, namely function composition).  But in your case, it sounds you are talking about a $V$ *which itself already has a multiplication on it*.

A vector space with a multiplication is usually called an algebra.  Every associative algebra is naturally a Lie algebra with the obvious Lie bracket $[a,b] = ab-ba$. I think you are considering the embedding of an arbitrary Lie algebra into the Lie algebra of an associative algebra. An important result in this direction is the [Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem).

In general, the purpose of representation theory is to study an object by studying its homomorphisms into some "easier" or "standard" object that we already understand, is more concrete, is easier to compute with, etc. In your case, it sounds like $V$ is this standard object.

Depending on what we're doing, we may demand that a representation is injective or surjective, but not usually both.  If it was both injective and surjective, then that means the original object is isomorphic to a "standard" object, but usually no such standard object exists (if it did, then we probably could just study the standard object and we would not need representations).

Having said that, if you have an injective representation, then yes, it is important to determine the image of the original object inside the standard object, so that we know which part of the standard object will help us understand the original object.  But that is not the same as demanding that the representation be surjective onto the standard object. That would be demanding that the standard object be isomorphic to the original object, and is too restrictive.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was sought after. You helped me to connect things together.

Comment: What kind of property can be studied by considering this kind of embedding?

Comment: If the image of the embedding inside the standard object is "nice", and the property you're studying has a "nice" description in terms of the standard object, then usually the embedding can help. If the embedding is "forced", or if you can't describe the property in the standard object without reference to the embedding, then the embedding may not be so helpful. I know this is very vague, but it's hard to be more concrete without a specific example.

Comment: I am reading a very old paper regarding the Baker-Hausdorff-Formula. They did it in two steps. First they constructed an embedding of a Lie ring into a associative free ring generated by X and Y such that the elements in this representation, which are called as Lie element, can be written in form of linear combination of successive applying Lie bracket on the generator. Then they showed that log(exp(X)exp(Y)) is an Lie element to close the argument for the existence of BCH formula. I just don’t understand why they used the embedding here.

Comment: Without seeing the paper, I would say that it's because in the associative algebra, the exp and log have concrete algebraic formulas, and you can manipulate these formulas easily due to the associative multiplication, as opposed to in the Lie algebra, where exp and log are defined abstractly and you only have a Lie bracket multiplication. If the embedding is injective and an equality involves only elements in the image of the embedding, then an equality on the associative side implies the corresponding equality in the original Lie algebra, which is what you wanted.

Comment: This is *exactly* the kind of situation where representations help - we "understand" associative algebras better than Lie algebras.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. I will read this again with all the points in mind. I think I have more clearer mind now. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67838/discussion-between-quallenjager-and-ted).